# Convert string name to entity

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create generic method that will take in a master entity type and populate the secondary entity class if it has anyone. I can get the master entity to populate with no issues but I'm having issues with populating the secondary classes.

This is what I have so far.

My stored procedure returns a master and secondary records.

[image: Returned SQL]

I have created method that takes the master entity and returns a dictionary of all the secondary classes.

[image: Secondary Class Method]

**Secondary classes population -**

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> dicItem in DTOParserFactory.GetEntityObjects(typeof(T).Name))
{
    reader.NextResult();
    if(reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader["ClassDtoType"].ToString() == dicItem.Key)
            {
                Type t = dicItem.Value.GetType();
                var b = Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                //if (dicItem.Key.Contains("List_"))
                //{
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. Get all the secondary classes for this master entity
2. Get the next set of data in the sqldatareader
3. Check if the reader has any records
4. Check that the current dictionary matches the sql ClassDtoType column

The main issue that I'm having is creating a class of the current entity, Eg:

**Contact newClass = New Contact();**

I would prefer not to pass the secondary classes through to this method and can keep it generic enough to handle any master and secondary class set.

Is this possible?

Thank you for the help, it is greatly apprecaited.
If you need anymore information, please let me know.